# Place Image from DLL onto a web page

Tags: c#, image, dll, web

I'm so stuck on something i thought would be easy.
I have a DLL that returns an Image object.
I just cant figure out how to display that image on a webpage.

I've tried a few ways, and google a million different variations.

Is it not possible to just bind an Image object to an element on the page like an HtmlImage or a simple img?

Or do i need to convert the Image to a Stream? or a Bitmap? I'm really stuck!

Any help appreciated.....

V

Comment: yes, you have to produce a stream containing the image bytes. Is the image in a resources file in the DLL ?

Comment: What are you using (WebForms, MVC...)?

Comment: @Steve B: no, the DLL literally returns an image. i can a method, pass it a few vars, and i get a chart back.

Comment: @Boris B: i'm using WebForms. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Asp.Net WebForm, the easiest way is to create a custom ashx file.

In Visual Studio, create a new Custom Handler (I'm not sure of the name of the template in Visual Studio). This will create a .ashx file.

In the code of this handler, write something like (does not have VS under the hand to test the syntax) :

```
public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{

   byte[] raw; 
   using(var ms = new MemoryStream()){
       Image myImage = GetFromDll();
       myImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
       raw=ms.ToArray();
   }
   context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
   context.Response.BinaryWrite(raw);
}
```

Then, in your browser, navigate to `http://yourserver/app/yourhandler.ashx.`

You can if you want add url parameter, and get it from the Request.QueryString collection

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as binding. On the client side images are retrieved from the web server as a separate GET request, which means you have to have a URL that resolves to an image. The other option, as Asif suggested, is embedding your image in the HTML as a Base64 string, which is bad practice for shared images (see Steve B's comment).

You either have to provide an URL (route that returns the image *file* in MVC, or a custom page with proper content type and Response.Write in WebForms), or embed in html.

EDIT:
There is also a third option involving custom HTTP handlers. These have the advantage of bypassing the app framework and serving the content almost directly off the web server, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to base64 string and then set it in the `<img/>` tag. 
`<img/>` can show the image in base64 string.

Alternatively you can save the image and use the path in the `<img/>`.

Comment: Very bad idea regarding performances. You'll add a great amount of data in the page, downloaded each time the page is download. If page weight is important for you, you should better create a custom handler that will serve the image binaries with the correct http headers for letting the browser cache the file.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the performance issue, @SteveB can you please explain the technique of creating custom handler in some detail, its interesting ...

Comment: @Asif http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096122/how-do-i-use-an-ashx-handler-with-an-aspimage-object