# Display image in formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem my picture is coming form database that is signature of the customer.

How can i bind that signature on the `Formview` using `<% #Eval() %>`

```
          <tr>
              <td>
                    Display Signature :
              </td>
              <td>
                    <%#Eval("SignatureImage") %>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: In my opinion, an image has to be included inside an `<img>` tag. Does your "SignatureImage" property emit an image tag?

Comment: What format is that signature. If its binary, you can either save it, either convert it to base64 inline image, either use a diferent handler to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the httphandler to retrieve the binary image, and then bind it to one image contorl with src property. Check this full sample code:

ImgHandler.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ImgHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public class ImgHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        string querySqlStr = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
        {
            querySqlStr="select * from testImageTable where ID="+context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"];
        }
        else
        {
            querySqlStr="select * from testImageTable";
        }
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDataBaseConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querySqlStr, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //get the extension name of image
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string name = reader["imageName"].ToString();
                int endIndex = name.LastIndexOf('.');
                string extensionName = name.Remove(0, endIndex + 1);
                buffer = (byte[])reader["imageContent"];
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + extensionName;
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <img src="ImgHandler.ashx?ImageID=1" alt="" />
        <img src="ImgHandler.ashx?ImageID=2" alt="" />
        <img src="ImgHandler.ashx?ImageID=3" alt="" />
        <img src="ImgHandler.ashx?ImageID=4" alt="" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't the HTTP Handler, please check the references below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096122/how-do-i-use-an-ashx-handler-with-an-aspimage-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096122/how-do-i-use-an-ashx-handler-with-an-aspimage-object)object