# Read Byte Array from <asp:Image ID="Image1" > in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I was using this to read byte

```
 string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Image1.ImageUrl);
 prsn.photo = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

But how to read byte array from

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Site/images/agent.png" Height="80px" Width="60px" runat="server" />
```

i have an image loaded to it when i am getting image1.uri then it returns path

```
"~/getCaseImg.aspx?caseid=1"
```

but now it is not reading byte array from this path

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Image1.ImageUrl);
prsn.photo = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use an .ashx handler with an asp:Image object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096122/how-do-i-use-an-ashx-handler-with-an-aspimage-object)

Comment: If you want to render image by handler (ascx/aspx) see duplicate. If you want to inline image on page as Base64 encoded data - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178737/convert-base64-to-image-in-c-sharp for value to be used for `ImageUrl`.